# How to split and get till 6 digit after the decimal of logitude in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am new to javascript and trying something with longitude coordinate.

**I have 3 longitudes and I want to split and store them till 6 digits after the decimal point**

I am able to do only one of them at a time which is not good as these numbers can come dynamically from user input.

**For example:**

```
let long1 = 151.21484501290186; // I want to store till 151.214845
let long2 = 77.55814612714227;  // I want to store till 77.558146
let long3 = -122.0898574222976; // I want to store till -122.089857

// this method only works if starting value is of 2 digits but failed when it's 3
const result = long2.toString().substr(long2.toString().indexOf('.') - 2, 9);
console.log(result) // 77.558146
```

Please help me.

Comment: Obviously change the 2 to a 6.

Comment: @mplungjan yes but I converted it back using ```parseFloat()``` :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get 6 decimals and keep as float, you can use

[toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

and convert back to number using parseFloat:

```
parseFloat(number.toFixed(6))
```

like this

```js
let longs = [151.21484501290186, // I want to store till 151.214845
 77.55814612714227,  // I want to store till 77.558146
 -122.0898574222976 // I want to store till -122.089857
 ]
 
longs =  longs.map(long => parseFloat(long.toFixed(6)))
console.log(longs)


// or just one of them
const long = 151.21484501290186;
const shorter = parseFloat(long.toFixed(6))
console.log(shorter)
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest way just use `toFixed()`

```js
let long1 = 151.21484501290186; // I want to store till 151.214845
let long2 = 77.55814612714227;  // I want to store till 77.558146
let long3 = -122.0898574222976; // I want to store till -122.089857

// this method only works if starting value is of 2 digits but failed when it's 3
const result = long2.toString().substr(long2.toString().indexOf('.') - 2, 9);

const result1 = long1.toFixed(6)
console.log(result) // 77.558146
console.log(result1)
```